# Convenient method to check if a list contains multiple elements

Tags: java, string, list

How can I check if a list of strings contains some specific strings at the same time, without having to do multiple contains.

For example something like this:

```
if (templist.contains("aaa") && templist.contains("bbb")) {

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List.containsAll` function can actually achieve your requirement. However, using  `containsAll` with list type can degrade in performance as the order is `O(NK)` where `N` is the number of elements of the list and K is the number of target string. Try using a **`HashSet`** to improve the performance:

```
   HashSet<String>set = new HashSet<>(list);
   if(set.containsAll(Arrays.asList("asd", "efg")))
        // do my job;
```

Because, [`HashSet<E>` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) offers *constant time performance* for the basic operations (`add, remove, contains and size`). As `containsAll` inherently uses the `contains` function to look up the element the order can be expected as `O(N+K)`

Comment: Correct point, but don't forget that creating a `HashSet` from the first `List` takes also more time and memory. So, you're indeed right if OP needs to check for `containsAll` multiple times, otherwise not.

Comment: @Alex, the order i have mention is `O(N +K)` which includes the time to create the set from the list: `O(N)` part. :)

Comment: That's right, I misread your answer. Actually, a simple benchmark shows that for a one shot, creating a HashSet from the first list and checking for containsAll is clearly longer for the first call, then it is largely faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
if (templist.containsAll(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb"))) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: if I do this means aaa and bbb must exist in the list right? @Alex

Comment: @user2598911: Read the javadoc. It explains what the method does: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29